# How do I fix iPhone SE celluar network after 12.1.2 upgrade?

Tags: iphone, ios

My iPhone SE was just upgraded with ios 12.1.2, but the cellular network is now dead.  After restarting it, I got this message

> Cellular Update Failed
>
> Your iPhone cannot make and receive calls or access cellular data until it has been updated.
>
> Learn More / OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this recent Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208733), you need to bring the iPhone to a Genius Bar or other authorized Apple repair place to have it fixed.

You can also [contact Apple Support](https://getsupport.apple.com/?caller=kbase&SG=SG003&category_id=SC0999&symptom_id=99976) to discuss your options.

Comment: Thanks @fsb, unfortunately I don't live in the US to bring the phone to a Genius Bar, and authorized resellers are not so good in my country, so that's going to be my last resort.

Comment: I think that's your only resort.  All the research I did said you need to take it in to be looked at.  You can try contacting Apple Support directly from the link in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, for your help.  It looks like I'm not the only one, see this article from yesterday in [forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2018/12/20/apple-ios-12-1-2-release-iphone-xs-max-xr-problem-4g-cellular-data-not-working/#7667ced7344b).

Comment: Yea, this is not the first time this problem has happened, either.  I was seeing articles from last year with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your cellular settings.

How to do so from [this Apple Support page:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201270)

> 1. Make sure your device is connected to a Wi-Fi or cellular network.
> 2. Tap Settings > General > About. If an update is available, you'll see an option to update your carrier settings.

If there is no option or it doesn't work then:

> If you see either of these alerts, take your iPhone or iPad to an
>   Apple Authorized Service Provider or make a Genius Bar reservation at
>   an Apple Store. You can also [contact Apple Support.](https://getsupport.apple.com/?caller=kbase&SG=SG003&category_id=SC0999&symptom_id=99976)

According to [this Apple Support page.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208733)