# No celullar signal after replacing battery, if not updating iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, software-update, cellular-data

I have an iPhone SE with iOS 13.6.1.
I have been receiving notifications of available OS updates, but I could use it with no problem.

Yesterday, I took it to a shop for a battery change.
Upon turning it on after the replacement, I got a notification which I cannot recover now.
But it stated something similar to what I now see when selecting *Cellular data* (translating from Spanish, the language of my cell phone), which is: *An update is required to use cellular data on this iPhone*.
Now I have *No Service*, so I have no cellular data, nor I can make/receive phone calls.

**So this update was previously *available*, but not *mandatory*.**

My questions:

1. **Is that change in behaviour normal/expected, after a battery change or some other action?**
2. **Can that be overcome and recover cellular data without an OS update?** (I'd prefer not to do the update right now, until I check if a slowing down of the phone is not expected)
   [Can I manually reset Cellular network configuration without losing WiFi passwords?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431697/can-i-manually-reset-cellular-network-configuration-without-losing-wifi-password) aims at trying this.

I know two possible suggestions of *what to do* are:

1. "Take it to the shop".
2. "Go ahead and update".

But I still want to know about the questions, and I guess neither A1 or A2 answer Q1 or Q2.
If possible, I want to know before taking the phone to the shop if I finally need to do that.

**Related**:

1. [How do I fix iPhone SE celluar network after 12.1.2 upgrade?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346348/how-do-i-fix-iphone-se-celluar-network-after-12-1-2-upgrade)

Comment: The 'slowing down' issue was solved years ago. If you'd rather your phone crashes than slows down [which was the prior alternative] you can just disable the slow-down. The rest of your question is answered in the one you linked to.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Please see EDITed OP. I understand you point, and I add: 
1) My phone was not crashing at all with 13.6.1, so I would still be ok with it.
2) Even if updating is ok, I want to know about the questions.
3) I recall reading about suspicious behaviour of "old" iPhones after updates, with noticeably short battery life... I can't give now precision about the source, iPhones/iOSs involved, and how credible was that.
4) I don't see answers to any of my two questions in any of the links. If you found them, would you mind pointing that out?