# Can I manually reset Cellular network configuration without losing WiFi passwords?

Tags: network, wifi, cellular-data, macos

I know I can reset network configuration, which: 1) resets cellular data, but 2) also removes all wifi passwords.

**Can I do #1 without #2?**

I mean to try that as a solution to [No celullar signal after replacing battery, if not updating iOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431695/no-celullar-signal-after-replacing-battery-if-not-updating-ios)

Comment: This entire issue is based on a moot point. Your phone is also insecure without the latest iOS.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I apologize in advance, but I don't quite see the connection between security and what is asked. The intention of resetting network configuration was not related to security issues, but to the linked question.

Comment: I mean you're only onto this line of enquiry because you don't want Apple to slow down your phone (though you're making the reader look through your question history to discover that). They fixed that years ago… so you're ducking & diving to try avoid something that is no longer a concern. That makes this whole line of questions an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) What **is** a concern is your phone is insecure.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Now I see your point. Even if I would be safe to update, the question is *per se* relevant, in some cases (I wouldn't dare quoting, but it's not a main point). I guess the fact that in iOS 15 Apple seems to have implemented it (see answer below) is enough proof of this. So the remaining question is now restricted to iOS <= 14.x.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a new feature, at least in iOS 15.1 you already have this option: Settings > Mobile Data > Mobile Data Network > Reset Settings

In previous iOS 14 was in Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings, but as you said unfortunately was removing the wifi passwords.

Comment: It is good to know, but it is useless for me at this point, since I don't have iOS 15, and I wanted to try this to avoid the update, precisely.